# How to put multiple breakpoints in fiddler?

Tags: ajax, wcf, fiddler

In fiddler we can put breakpoints by follwoing commands:-

`[bpv or bpm]` Create a request breakpoint for the specified HTTP method.  Setting this command will clear any previous value for the command; calling it with no parameter will disable the breakpoint. bpv POST
bpv        <-- Call with no parameter to clear

`[bpu]`  Create a request breakpoint for URIs containing the specified string.  Setting this command will clear any previous value for the command; calling it with no parameter will disable the breakpoint. bpu /myservice.asmx
bpu

I want to break on the request if

a) If request is made for `http://url_1/dummy1.svc`

b) If request is made for `http://url_2/dummy2.svc/DoWork` (called from yui ajax request)

Both the url are making POST request. So I tried with `bpv POST` command, but it breaks only for 'a' scenario.

I gave `bpu http://url_2/dummy2.svc/DoWork` and `bpv POST` command. But It seems `bpv` work but not `bpu`. If I give `bpv POST` and `bpu http://url_2/dummy2.svc/DoWork` then `bpu` works but not `bpv`.

Let me know the way how I can use both `bpu` and `bpv` at same time?

How can I use fiddler to capture both urls request?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the AutoResponder tab.

Add two new entries with the Rules and ActionText as follows:

```
http://url_1/dummy1.svc           *bpu
http://url_2/dummy2.svc/DoWork    *bpu
```

Alternatively, click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to `OnBeforeRequest` and add

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST"))
{
    // Careful, URLs are Case-Sensitive...
    if ((oSession.fullUrl == "http://url_1/dummy1.svc") ||
        (oSession.fullUrl == "http://url_1/dummy2.svc/DoWork"))
    {
        oSession["X-BreakRequest"] = "script";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the built-in rules code in Fiddler (type ctrl-r in Fiddler), here is how breakpoints are set:

```
if ((null!=bpRequestURI) && oSession.uriContains(bpRequestURI)) {
    oSession["x-breakrequest"]="uri";
}

if ((null!=bpMethod) && (oSession.HTTPMethodIs(bpMethod))) {
    oSession["x-breakrequest"]="method";
}
```

This logic implies that the URI and Method based breakpoints are mutually exclusive. I don't know enough about creating custom rules to know if a composite rule can be created that does what you need.

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive, they're just unrelated.